# Ruby check if even number, float

Tags: ruby

I want to check if the number is even!
I tried the following:

```
a = 4.0
a.is_a? Integer

=> false

a.even?

=> undefined method for Float
```

So how can i check if the number is even?

Comment: Ok in my case i only have to test if the number has in the second charakter an 5 like in 0.5 or 3.5!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are unsure if your variable has anything after the decimal and would like to check before converting to integer to check odd/even, you could do something like this:

```
a = 4.6
b = 4.0

puts a%1==0 && a.to_i.even? #=> false
puts b%1==0 && a.to_i.even? #=> true
```

Additionally, if you want to create an even? method for the Float class:

```
class Float
  def even?
    self%1==0 && self.to_i.even?
  end
end

a = 4.6
b = 4.0

a.even? #=> false
b.even? #=> true
```

Answer (score 5):

Make it an `Integer` then:

```
a = 4.0
a.to_i == a && a.to_i.even?  #=> true
```

Comment: But when i have an number like 0.5 it also returns true!

Comment: I don't think 4.2 is considered even.

Comment: @JohnSmith That should be added to the question, I thought you mean it's an integer of type `Float`.

Comment: You could just do a.to_i.even?

Answer (score 2):

Just keep in mind how numbers are converted:

```
(4.0).to_i # same as Integer(4.0)
=> 4
(4.5).to_i
=> 4
(4.9).to_i
=> 4
```

Using `round` may be safer:

```
(4.0).round
=> 4
(4.5).round
=> 5
(4.9).round
=> 5
```

Then of course you can call `even` as @Yu Hao wrote:

```
(4.5).round.even?
=> false
```

You can also easily observe known floats 'feature':

```
(4.499999999999999).round.even?
=> true
(4.4999999999999999).round.even?
=> false
```