# Extend the number class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extend the number class to have instance functions such as `odd` and `even` so I can do something like this:

```
2.odd() => false
2.even() => true
1.even() => false
1.odd()  => true
```

Extending classes is a good Ruby practise: "[Ruby check if even number, float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163475/ruby-check-if-even-number-float)".

Is the same true in JavaScript, or does it cause performance issues or some other problem?

Anyway, I can't extend despite my best efforts:

```
var NumberInstanceExtensions = {
    accuracy: function(){
        return 'This is cool ' + this
    }
}
$.extend(Number.prototype,NumberInstanceExtensions);

alert( $.type(5) );      //-> number
//alert( 5.accuracy() ); //-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VLPTb/2/

How can I get this to work? The syntax error makes me think this isn't how JavaScript works on a fundamental level. Is my best bet extending the Math class and doing this instead:

```
Math.odd(2)  => false
Math.even(2) => true
Math.even(1) => false
Math.odd(1)  => true
```

That seems far more inelegant than `2.odd()`.

Comment: Extending classes is generally not good practice in javascript, but as long as you know the consequences there's nothing inherently wrong in doing so either.

Comment: And note that you can't chain a method on a number directly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VLPTb/4/

Comment: @Starkers Why would you extend a prototype or create a function that does what one line of code would do anyways? someNum % 2 === 0 is pretty succinct as it is...

Comment: @dudewad Makes it more self documenting and readable `if number.is_even() ...` ect

Comment: @Starkers yeah, it does, but it also means you've loaded down your prototype or done a custom mod that in itself is going to require more documentation. HOWEVER! I think it's a fantastic idea as long as you can ensure that you'll have no side-effects. As I said in my post below I modify the string prototype once in a while for what is essentially the same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think as long as you understand the side-effects of your "extension" then you're okay. I often modify the String prototype to add an "elipsis" method so I can do things like

```
"SomeString".elipsis()
```

But start at the beginning. You're not "extending classes" in JavaScript. JavaScript is a prototype-based language. You can modify prototypes to do what you need.

You won't be able to add a method directly to the number itself. You can, however modify the prototype of the Number object:

```
Number.prototype.even = function(){    
    return this.valueOf() % 2 === 0;
}
```

With this, you won't be able to use the following syntax:

```
10.even();
```

But, since you aren't hard-coding stuff, otherwise you wouldn't need this function anyways, you CAN do the following:

```
var a = 10;
a.even(); //true
```

I might say that you could consider adding a utilities object to do these things, because modifying primitive prototypes is not always guaranteed to be side-effect free.

This function does not really provide any gain for you. You're checking for odd and even, replacing one line of code with another. Think about the difference:

```
var a = 10;
var aIsEven = a.even();
```

vs:

```
var a = 10;
var aIsEven = a % 2 === 0;
```

You gain three characters of code, and the second option is less likely to break your "JavaScript".

Comment: Thanks dudewad! But then, how can I do this? `console.log( ['zero','one'].extract(0) );`, if extract is my own extension? Just wondering, not that you matters. As you say, I'm always going to be running these functions in variables rather than hard coded values

Comment: console.log requires strings so whatever output you get from your extract call needs to be a string.

Comment: You can do 10..even() (2 dots)

Answer (score 3):

You *can* extend natives JS objects  by using (for example) `Number.prototype.myFn = function(){}`.

<strike>So you could do :</strike>

```
Math.prototype.odd = function(n){
    return n % 2 === 0;
};

Math.prototype.even = function(n){
    return n % 2 === 1;
};
```

And then use it like so :

```
var two = 2;
console.log(Math.odd(2)); // true
```

BUT I would *strongly* advise you against extending natives in JavaScript.
You can read more about it [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/)

**EDIT** : After trying my code on JSFiddle, it appears the `Math` object has no `prototype`, you can [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820554/why-is-math-prototype-undefined). **The code above won't work !**

Instead, you could do :

```
Math.odd = function(n){
    return n % 2 === 0;
};

Math.even = function(n){
    return n % 2 === 1;
};

console.log(Math.odd(2)); // true
```

*or :*

```
Number.prototype.odd = function(){
    return this % 2 === 0;
};

Number.prototype.even = function(){
    return this % 2 === 1;
};

console.log(new Number(2).odd()); // true
```

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to point out that that is already available in the numbers class.

Just use the boolean methods, odd? and even?

```
2.odd?
=> false

2.even?
=> true
```

Hope this helps.

No need to create a new class, it already exists in the numbers class.

Comment: 2.odd? => 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
... and ...
2.even => 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
... Is your example javascript?

Comment: Use 2 dots 10..even()

Comment: My mistake, I saw this under the Ruby tag so I assumed it was Ruby. My apologies, I didn't realize you wanted this in JavaScript

Comment: @RainbowManiac No worries

Comment: If the answer doesn't make sense at all why not delete it?